# how to remove outside quotes from python list ['(20, [50, 45], [456.6, 5675])']?

Tags: python, list, quotes

How can I remove simple quotes from this list: `['(20, [50, 45], [456.6, 5675])']`
I spent a lot of time looking for a solution.

I will be very thankful.

Comment: That's just a list whose only element is a string. I don't think the idea of "removing quotes" makes much sense, I'm not sure what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, we can use literal eval from the ast library.

```
from ast import literal_eval

new_list = [literal_eval(i) for i in your_list]
```

---

```
print(new_list)

[(20, [50, 45], [456.6, 5675])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
my_list = ['(20, [50, 45], [456.6, 5675])']
```

---

```
from ast import literal_eval
list(map(literal_eval, my_list))
#[(20, [50, 45], [456.6, 5675])]
```

if not all are str could fail so:

```
my_list = ['(20, [50, 45], [456.6, 5675])',1]
list(map(lambda x: literal_eval(x) if isinstance(x,str) else x,my_list))
#[(20, [50, 45], [456.6, 5675]), 1]
```